# WPF multiple GridSplitters and a "star-width" column

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this simple XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="LightCoral" MinWidth="100"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="LightBlue" MinWidth="100"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Fill="LightCoral" MinWidth="100"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="3" Fill="Gray" MinWidth="100"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="4" Fill="LightCoral" MinWidth="100"/>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

</Grid>
```

This one works well, but I want to have the second column (one that holds the LightBlue rectangle) - to fill all available width. If I set the 2nd ColumnDefinition.Width="*" - then GridSplitters to the right side of it, lets say Gray rectangle's GridSplitter - it starts acting very wierd and quite not what I want. Is it possible to make GridSplitters to behave like in DataGrid's column headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create separate columns for your `GridSplitter` controls

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="LightCoral" MinWidth="100"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Fill="LightBlue"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="4" Fill="LightCoral" MinWidth="100"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="6" Fill="Gray" MinWidth="100"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="8" Fill="LightCoral" MinWidth="100"/>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                  Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ResizeDirection="Columns" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                  Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ResizeDirection="Columns" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="5" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                  Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ResizeDirection="Columns" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="7" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                  Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ResizeDirection="Columns" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: No, I see almost no change. At least when I try to set ColumnDefinition[2].Width="*" - it still behaves wrong

Comment: @AlexeyTitov I think I can see what you mean. Can you try using * for your column widths? I know this doesn't have the same initial column sizing as you have currently, but it works better.

Comment: Yes, not quite what I want, but still, your answer will do for my project specs with *initial* AR 16:9 or 16:10. Thanks!